# wxpython - How to make buttons disable if something in the programm happens?

Tags: button, wxpython

I am programming for a project in school and i kind of stuck in very simple thing that i just can't solve. the programm is a GUI of the game BULLS AND COWS.
I do it with buttons of numbers, that every click on each of them, add the selected number to a text box. Due to the rules of the game, there must be only 4 numbers before the turn is over, so what i am trying to do is making the buttons disable if there are already 4 numbers in the text box.
Here is the code:

```
import wx
from random import randint

OPTIONS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "DEL", 0, "SEND"]
# these are the events' IDs sent to a function when you click a button.
# the OPTIONS_ID is in the same order of OPTIONS.

OPTIONS_ID = [-31990,-31989,-31988,-31987,-31986,-31985, -31984, -31983, -31982, -31981, -31980, -31979]  # the built in wxpython IDs for the buttons


GAME_POSITION = (400, 100)
GAME_SIZE = [900, 600]

class Frame(wx.Frame):  # class for all the frames in our game.

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.fdf = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(275, 75), pos=(520, 20))
        self.count = 0
        self.check = False
    # this function creates a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
    def write(self, panel, txt, pos, size=20, font_family=wx.SWISS, font_style = wx.NORMAL,font_weight = wx.BOLD, underline = False):
        # create a textbox at a specific position with a specific size.
        your_txt = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, txt, pos)
        your_txt.SetFont(wx.Font(size,font_family,font_style,font_weight,underline))
    # same as above, just for a button.
    def create_button(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: self.OnButton(evt), self.button)
    def create_disable(self, panel, txt, position, width, height):
        Size = wx.Size(width, height)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, -1, txt, position, Size)
        self.border = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.border.Add(self.button)
        self.button.Disable()
    def OnButton(self, event):
        print repr(event.Id) + ","
        if event.Id in OPTIONS_ID:  # if indeed an option button was pressed
            exited = -1  # exited is 5100 if the user exited his dialog box
            # assigning the events to the button.
            if event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[0]:  # 1
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[0]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[1]:  # 2
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[1]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[2]:  # 3
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[2]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[3]:  # 4
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[3]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[4]:  # 5
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[4]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[5]:  # 6
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[5]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[6]:  # 7
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[6]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[7]:  # 8
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[7]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[8]:  # 9
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[8]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[9]:  # del
                if self.count > 0:
                    self.count -= 1
                self.fdf.SetValue(self.fdf.GetValue()[:-1])
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[10]:  # 0
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[10]))
                self.count += 1
            elif event.Id == OPTIONS_ID[11]:  # send
                self.fdf.AppendText(str(OPTIONS[11]))
            if self.count == 4:
                print "ddd"


class Game(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):  # upon game opening
        # I would like the options window to be the first window's parent
        # so I will first set up our options window:
        window = Frame(None, -1, "Good Luck!", GAME_POSITION, GAME_SIZE)
        first_panel = window.panel
        window.write(first_panel, "BULLS AND COWS!", (50, 50), size=(35))
        countX = 500
        countY = 100
        for option in OPTIONS:
            window.create_button(first_panel,str(option), (countX, countY), 100, 100)
            countX += 110
            if str(option) == "3" or str(option) == "6" or str(option) == "9":
                countY += 110
                countX = 500



        window.Show(True)
        return True


def main():
    camel = Game()
    camel.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to do this with counter variable that count every click of one of the buttons, and when he equals to 4 (it means that there are 4 numbers in the text box), then something happens (in the code i told him to print the string "ddd" for no reason). The question is: how do i make the buttons to disable when there is 4 numbers (instead of printing "ddd")? I am aware of the command button.Disable(), but i have no idea where to put it in order to make it work, and i failed with all of my attempts.

I hope you help me.. :)

Comment: Just to clarify: Once the counter reaches 4, you want to disable *all* the buttons?

Comment: all of the numbers buttons (of course that the "delete" and the "send" buttons will be able to be pressed) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all the buttons once the counter reaches 4, use the `GetChildren()` method on the container. In this case, that is `self.panel`, which is the parent for all the buttons. Simply calling `self.panel.GetChildren()` would give you *all* the children, though, not just the buttons.

Fortunately, Python has the built-in function `isinstance()` to check if an object is of the given class. To ensure we are only disabling the buttons, we check that `isinstance(button, wx.Button)` returns true, indicating that the object is indeed an instance of `wx.Button`.

Limiting this to just numbered buttons complicates it slightly, but not by too much. Simply check the label of the button! Here's how you can do that:

```
...
if self.count == 4:
    for child in self.panel.GetChildren():
        if isinstance(child, wx.Button):
            try:
                int(child.GetLabel())
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                child.Disable()
...
```

First, we loop through all children of your panel. On the next line, we check to make sure the child is actually a button, and not a static text or anything like that. Finally, we check to see if the label is an integer. If it's not (and it throws a ValueError), we ignore it; if it is, we disable it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! it's work perfectlly. How can i learn more about this topic (what is childrens and parents and how to use them)? I guess that it will be very useful to me..

Comment: Now i noticed in a little error..
if i put 4 numbers it is work exactly like i want (disable all the numbers buttons), but if after that i delete one number, than count becomes to 3 - but the numbers buttons are still disables. 
how can i fix this?
And here i want to say also that English is not my native language so i probably have some grammer mistakes.. sory ;)

Comment: I fixed it myself! sorry for the unnecessary question.. Haha
And again, thak you for your help, i realy appreciate it.

Comment: The children in this case are the children widget of the panel. When you pass `self.panel` to the button widget, you are setting that widget's `parent` parameter to be `self.panel`. Thus, the panel object is the parent of multiple widgets.